# Transforming SQL query using Doctrine Query Builder

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine, left-join

SQL - is correct and works in mysql-console. I have some SQL query which I use for selection from database products. I have tried just to put it into the repository, but it didn't work at all.

Also here's a code of function of ProductRepository

Could somebody help me or show my mistake and explain how to transform SQL into a query builder query or force to work pure SQL?

```
SELECT *
FROM accounting_products
LEFT JOIN accounting_incoming_invoice_items 
    ON accounting_incoming_invoice_items.product_id = accounting_products.id
WHERE accounting_incoming_invoice_items.outcome_price >
          accounting_incoming_invoice_items.price;
```

```
    public function findAllOnStorage()
    {
        $rsm = new ResultSetMapping($this->getEntityManager());

        $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createNativeQuery(
            "SELECT * FROM accounting_products LEFT JOIN accounting_incoming_invoice_items 
                    ON accounting_incoming_invoice_items.product_id = accounting_products.id
                    WHERE accounting_incoming_invoice_items.outcome_price > accounting_incoming_invoice_items.price;",
            $rsm);

        $all = $query->getResult();
        #dump($all);exit;
        return $all;
    }
```

If in repository pure SQL - it just doesn't work. The results of the query are the empty set, but in console, it returns exactly one record

Tries to transform SQL into a query builder hadn't any success.

Comment: Your LEFT JOIN returns regular INNER JOIN result. Move the accounting_incoming_invoice_items condition from WHERE to ON to get true LEFT JOIN result.

Answer (score 0):

```
$qrBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->select('p', 'i')
    ->leftJoin(IncomingInvoiceItem::class, 'i')
    ->where('i.outcomePrice > i.price');


$all = $qrBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
```

But MariaDB still throwing error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE a1_.outcome_price > a1_.price' at line 1
```